# Android send data from Thread in separate java class to UI thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, bluetooth

I have my MainActivity, ConnectThread and ConnectedThread in separate classes.

I am listening to a lot of data from a Bluetoothmodule in ConnectedThread.

I have the Broadcastreciever in my Main thread like this:

```
final BroadcastReceiver bReciever = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra("data");

        if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)){                // Bluetooth discovery result found
            BTArrayAdapter_found_filter.clear();             //Remove Duplicates
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            BTArrayAdapter_found.add(device.getName()+"\n"+device.getAddress());
            BTArrayAdapter_found.notifyDataSetChanged();

            for(int i = 0;i< BTArrayAdapter_found.getCount();i++){      // Iterate original Arrayadapter for filtering
                String filter = "RCD";

                if(BTArrayAdapter_found.getItem(i).toString().toLowerCase().contains(filter.toLowerCase())){

                    BTArrayAdapter_found_filter.add(BTArrayAdapter_found.getItem(i));
                    BTArrayAdapter_found_filter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                }
            }
        }
        if(message!=null)
        textview_terminal.setText(message);


    }
};
```

I would listen to the message and pass it to a textview. The other is just the Bluetooth part which is not relevant here.

I have the Intent in the ConnectedThread like this:

```
public void sendData(){
    Intent sendDataIntent = new Intent("SendData_EVENT");
    sendDataIntent.putExtra("data",passData);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance().sendBroadcast(sendDataIntent);

}
```

But as that thread has no connection to an Activity the Broadcastmanagers getInstance doesn't work.

I was trying to use this example: [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802157/how-to-use-localbroadcastmanager)

I had a look on a lot of examples and i don't think handlers are the best method for me.

How can i succesfully send the data from my background Thread?

SOLVED by sending sending getApplicationContext() to ConnectedThread constructor and passing that to getInstance(context)

Comment: have you registered the **BroadcastReceiver**?

Comment: Yes, i have LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(bReciever, new IntentFilter("SendData_EVENT"));
in the OnCreate of the Mainactivity, my problem is the LocalBroadcastmanager.getinstante() i cant put any arguments in there as the ConnectedThread is just a thread with no context or activity if i understand that correctly.

Comment: may be you can move logic from **threads** to **services**. It can help you. Don't forget service works in UI thread by default.

Comment: Won't that jeopardize the whole process? Inputstream.read block the process so i figured i need a thread, as per the developer docs too. And i need constant data stream, for example gps data.

Comment: read about [service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html). I think it's what you need

Comment: SOLVED by sending sending getApplicationContext() to ConnectedThread constructor and passing that to getInstance(context)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED by sending sending getApplicationContext() to ConnectedThread constructor and passing that to getInstance(context)